# What does G/IG signify in the galaxy names ESO 012- G 014 and ESO 293-IG 034?

Tags: galaxy, nasa, star-catalogues

The NASA/IPAC EXTRAGALACTIC DATABASE (NED) lists galaxies from the European Southern Observatory (ESO) catalog as  G  ([ESO 012- G 014](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/objsearch?extend=no&hconst=73&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA%20or%20Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES&objname=ESO%20012-%20G%20014)) or  IG  ([ESO 293-IG 034](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/objsearch?extend=no&hconst=73&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA%20or%20Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES&objname=ESO%20293-IG%20034)).

**What does G/IG signify?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These identifiers correspond to [the ESO/Uppsala Survey of the ESO(B) Atlas (1982)](https://cdsarc.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/VII/34C). The identifier column (ESO) is associated with the following note:

> ```
> Note (1)  : ESO designation is written FFF-oooNNN, where
> FFF = Field (plate) number, see file "plates.dat"
> ooo = Object class with
> * = star ** = double or multiple star
> SC = star cluster N = nebula
> A = asteroid C = comet
> G = galaxy IG = interacting galaxy
> EN = emission nebula PN = planetary nebula
> RN = reflection nebula SNR = supernova remnant
> ? = questionable object
> NNN = number within field
> ```

So the "G" means "galaxy" and "IG" means "interacting galaxy".